# Monitorar se o evento change ocorreu em um curto espaço de tempo

Tags: jquery

Eu tenho em meu framework um disparador que envia o dado do `input` `onchange` pra um model que valida e devolve, nesse processo tem um problema, cada caractere digitado é feita uma submissão, o que eu estou tentando fazer é a função descrita abaixo (não quero usar socket pra isso por enquanto):

> Quando há uma mudança no valor do input verificar se houve outra mudança dentro de 0.5 segundos, se não houver dispara algo, se houver aguardar mais 0.5 para disparar verificar se houve outra mudança e assim sucessivamente.

Até agora cheguei nisso:

```js
$(document).on('change keyup','input',function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
 e.preventDefault();
        var text = $this.val();
         setTimeout(function(){
                var text2 = $this.val();
                if(text !== text2){
                    //dispara o mesmo evento de novo
                    console.log('houve mudança de :'+ text + 'para: ' +text2);
                }else{
                   //dispara algum função
                   console.log('manteve o valor de: '+text);
                }
            }, 500);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
```

Aparentemente isso está dando certo, o que eu quero saber é:

- > Isso na verdade não está acumulando eventos disparados no mesmo
  >   trigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, irá acumular eventos.

Como a cada mudança e tecla pressionada você agenda a execução de uma função com `setTimeout`, você pode pressionar várias teclas antes desse intervalo acabar, e em cada tecla um novo agendamento é criado. No final, no console verá uma enxurrada de mensagens parecidas após o fim do primeiro intervalo.

### O que fazer?

Para você disparar o evento depois de determinado tempo somente **após a última tecla**, você precisa cancelar o timeout anterior e lançar outro:

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change keyup', 'input', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $this.val();
    // verifica se o elemento já agendou a execução da função pelo setTimeout
    var timeoutId = $this.data('timeoutId');
    console.log('this.value antes do setTimeout', text);
    console.log('timeoutId inicial', timeoutId);
    // já temos algum agendamento?
    if (timeoutId !== undefined) {
      console.log('clearing timeoutId', timeoutId);
      // cancela o agendamento feito anteriormente
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    }
    // agenda a função e guarda o valor retornado
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      var text2 = $this.val();
      console.log('texto agora', text2);
      console.log('manteve o valor?', text === text2);
      // remove o dado do elemento após a execução
      $this.removeData('timeoutId');
    }, 1000);
    console.log('timeoutId retornado de setTimeout', timeoutId);
    // guarda o valor retornado do setTimeout no próprio elemento
    $this.data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="" placeholder="digita alguma coisa aqui..." />
```

Enchi de comentários e de log, mas os comentários da função agendada só aparecem depois de passar o intervalo contando a partir do último evento.

### Mais informações

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout
- https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout